# Python - how can I run separate module (not function) as a separate process?

Tags: python, pytest, python-multiprocessing, bottle

tl,dr: How can I programmably execute a python module (not function) as a separate process from a different python module?

On my development laptop, I have a 'server' module containing a bottle server.  In this module, the name==main clause starts the bottle server.

```
@bt_app.post("/")
def server_post():
    << Generate response to 'http://server.com/' >>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(bt_app, port=localhost:8080)
```

I also have a 'test_server' module containing pytests.  In this module, the name==main clause runs pytest and displays the results.

```
def test_something():
        _rtn = some_server_function()
        assert _rtn == desired

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _rtn = pytest.main([__file__])
    print("Pytest returned: ", _rtn)
```

Currently, I manually run the server module (starting the web server on localhost), then I manually start the pytest module which issues html requests to the running server module and checks the responses.

Sometimes I forget to start the server module.  No big deal but annoying.  So I'd like to know if I can programmatically start the server module as a separate process from the pytest module (just as I'm doing manually now) so I don't forget to start it manually.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Put the `serve` line into a function. While doing that you can also fix the port syntax.

Comment: Klaus.  You CAN'T think that my minimal example is an actual program.

Answer (score 1):

There is my test cases dir tree:

```
test
├── server.py
└── test_server.py
```

`server.py` start a web server with flask.

```
from flask import Flask                                                                                                                                                
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`test_server.py` make request to test.

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                             
import requests
import subprocess
import time

p = None  # server process

def start_server():
    global p
    sys.path.append('/tmp/test')
    # here you may want to do some check. 
    # whether the server is already started, then pass this fucntion
    kwargs = {}  # here u can pass other args needed
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python','server.py'], **kwargs)

def test_function():
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/')
    print('This is response body: ', response.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()
    time.sleep(3)  # waiting server started
    test_function()
    p.kill()
```

Then you can do `python test_server` to start the server and do test cases.

PS: `Popen()` needs python3.5+. if older version, use `run` instead

Comment: tomy - Ahh.  I see.  The subprocess docs make it seem so very complicated.  Thanks for this example.  It's not as bad as it seems.  I'm still leaning to os.system, but if it can't do everything I need, I'll be using your example for subprocess. -- Thanks

Comment: @Den
From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) here.

It says:
`This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:
os.system
os.spawn*`

finally, u'll  leave these older packages....

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
import threading
import time

def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing", name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    threads = list()
    for index in range(3):
        logging.info("Main    : create and start thread %d.", index)
        x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(index,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()

    for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
        logging.info("Main    : before joining thread %d.", index)
        thread.join()
        logging.info("Main    : thread %d done", index)
```

With threading you can run multiple processes at once!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the threading module.  But threading is not multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Wim baasically answered this question.  I looked into the subprocess module.  While reading up on it, I stumbled on the os.system function.

In short, subprocess is a highly flexible and functional program for running a program.  os.system, on the other hand, is much simpler, with far fewer functions.

Just running a python module is simple, so I settled on os.system.

```
import os
server_path = "python -m ../src/server.py"
os.system(server_path)
```

Wim, thanks for the pointer.  Had it been a full fledged answer I would have upvoted it.  Redo it as a full fledged answer and I'll do so.

Answer (score 0):

Async to the rescue.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, spawn
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

@bt_app.post("/")
def server_post():
    << Generate response to 'http://server.com/' >>

def test_something():
    _rtn = some_server_function()
    assert _rtn == desired
    print("Pytest returned: ",_rtn)
    sleep(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spawn(test_something) #runs async
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080, bt_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```